# Can I pass the same matrix pointer as both the "C" and "A" matrix in cblas_gemm(...)?

Tags: c++, c, blas

I want to update C with the value C*B. I would also like to update C with the value C*C.

It is safe to do this? I do not want to give my students bad code. I am currently copying a temporary result from cblas_gemm(...) back to the C matrix... which is slow.

Comment: Is there any quick way to just test this in code?  I think that's probably the most straight forward way to see.  Though, I'm not familiar with blas...

Comment: I don't believe it is safe to do so, although the behaviour is implementation specific and what might work on one flavour of blas might fail on another. But are you sure GEMM is what you need? what about SYRK?

Answer (score 4):

If it were safe to use the same matrix as both input and output, the BLAS implementation would need to use a temporary workspace. Since you did not provide such a workspace because the function did not request one, we can conclude that you cannot use the same matrix as input  and output.

In fact, if a BLAS routine is going to accept a parameter as both input and output, then it would do so by using one parameter rather than two and documenting that the parameter is used for both input and output.

You say that using a temporary output variable and then copying after the BLAS call is slow. But that copy operation should be insignificant in comparison the the matrix multiply. Are you sure that the copy is a bottleneck? Did you time it?

Answer (score 1):

> I  want to update C with the value C*B. I would also like to update C with the value C*C. It is safe to do this?

No. `cgemm` and friends require that the input and output matrices don't overlap.

> I am currently copying a temporary result from cblas_gemm(...) back to the C matrix... which is slow.

Copying isn't slow. `memcpy` is O(n) with a very low constant factor. Matrix multiplication is O(n^2) with a higher constant factor.

Perhaps instead of a `memcpy`, you're copying the matrices element-by-element using nested `for` loops and doing it in an unoptimized (debug) build?

Or you're constantly allocating and deallocating the temporary matrix? If a computation needing the temporary matrix is repeated many times, allocate that matrix once and leave it allocated until the need is over.

Answer (score 0):

The BLAS standard ([available here](http://www.netlib.org/blas/blast-forum/)) just says:

> The routine performs a general matrix matrix multiply where .... A, B and C are general matrices.

so, I'd say it's implementation defined, and you can assume that it might be unsafe to do so.  However, if you're using a particular implementation, you could always check the source of that implementation.

Alternatively, as a commenter suggests, SYRK might do what you want.

Comment: syrk is for symmetric matrices